# DocuSign inbox empty, Settings for receiving acknowledgement in inbox

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts, powerform

I used to get PowerForm acknowledgment mails in my DocuSign inbox once the form submitted by the user.

When I check the last day I found all the emails are missing and not receiving emails anymore. The 'Sent' folder is fine. I am receiving in my admin email id (The email id used to create the account). Do I miss any settings for receiving emails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're using PowerForms so I'm basing this answer on that. It could be that the Sending Notifications are set incorrectly or you're not the actual sender of the PowerForm anymore. To check your notification settings, you can login to DocuSign and click on your profile at the top right > My Preferences > Notifications > and under 'Sending Notifications', ensure 'An envelope is complete' is checked.

To ensure that you're still the sender of the PowerForm, login to DocuSign and click on 'Templates' > find and click on the template with the PowerForm associated with it > under 'Associated PowerForms' click the 'Actions' drop-down > 'Change Sender', this will show who the current sender of the PowerForm is.